# Остаются нули после использования array_unique

Tags: php

Добрый день!

Дано: исходный массив 6,5 млн элементов - чисел, обрабатываю его array_unique, получаю 1,65 млн записей. Но, как выяснилось, из них 490 тысяч - нули. "0". В исходных данных нулей нет вообще. Это нормально?

UPDATE: при этом код, приведенный ниже, тоже говорит, что уникальных элементов 1,65 млн.

```
$sqlzstr = "SELECT DISTINCT  uid FROM group2user";
            $sqlz = mysql_query($sqlzstr,$db)
                    or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
            $count = 0;
            while ($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($sqlz, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            echo $count;
```

Comment: @nvdtz, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 0;
            while ($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($sqlz, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            echo $count;
```

замените на `echo mysql_num_rows($sqlz)`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий метод:

```
// Алгоритм: поменять местами ключи с их значениями и получить все ключи
// Объяснение: ключи в массиве уникальные по определению
$unique = array_keys(array_flip($array));
```